# Выполнить urllib request через proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, urllib

Возникла задачка, не могу понять в чём ошибка. Нужно обратиться к сайту через прокси.
Использую адрес с сайта, содержащим Free Proxy. Адрес пингуется

```
from urllib import request

hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Yandex'}

# Proxy support
proxy = request.ProxyHandler({
    'https': 'https://12.218.209.130:53281',
    'http': 'https://12.218.209.130:53281'
    })
    
req = request.Request("https://www.google.com", headers=hdr)
opener = request.build_opener(proxy)
request.install_opener(opener)
resp = request.urlopen(req, timeout=5)
charset = resp.info().get('charset', 'utf-8')        
print(resp.read().decode(charset))
```

В результате получаю ошибку по тайм-ауту

Вопрос: где и что я не корректно реализую?

Comment: Прокси не рабочие

Comment: Код рабочий - прокси отваливаются. Проверил с     {'https': 'https://45.147.200.102:3128',} - код отработал

Answer (score 0):

Код рабочий - прокси отваливаются.

Проверил с

```
proxy = request.ProxyHandler({'https': 'https://45.147.200.102:3128',})
```

код отработал